# unsupported language in windows app submission

Tags: cordova, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2015, windows, visual-studio-cordova

I Am getting the following error in windows app submission process:

[image]

> Package acceptance validation error: The package CordovaApp.Windows_1.1.0.0_anycpu.appxupload declares one or more unsupported languages: ps.

No similar errors while publishing for Android nor iOS.

**Adding project structure due to a comment request**

[image]

Comment: I've seen an issue like this when the Bing Maps SDK is used (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7892b407-e465-48cb-98d9-d800acc40457/package-with-unsupported-languages-svsc?forum=wpsubmit). Any chance you're using that SDK, or another? Can you share the folder structure under the res folder in your project?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not using that SDK... Added.

Comment: If you look in this file, do you see a <Resource Language="ps... item in the XML?  <project folder>\bin\Windows-AnyCPU\Debug\AppxManifest.xml

Comment: Yes i see this line there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone facing the same problem.

@Jordan Matthiesen(Thanks!) told me to check the file:

```
<project folder>\bin\Windows-AnyCPU\Debug\AppxManifest.xml
```

for the line:

```
<Resource Language="ps" />
```

It was there for some reason, but deleting it won't help as a comment in that file says:

```
THIS PACKAGE MANIFEST FILE IS GENERATED BY THE BUILD PROCESS.

Changes to this file will be lost when it is regenerated. To correct errors in this file, edit the source .appxmanifest file.

For more information on package manifest files, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241727
```

So I edited every *.appxmanifest under

```
<project folder>\platforms\windows\
```

Deleting the weird line.

And problem was solved.